# sed command to replace newline character is not working in solaris but working in linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, solaris

I have following sed command working in linux box. but the same is not working in solaris box. Please correct me what the problem is ?

```
a=`sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' file.txt`
```

**Throws,**

```
-bash-3.00$ a=`sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' file.txt`
Label too long: :a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed` on `solaris` you'll have to break it up like this:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 'N;$!ba' -e 's/\n/ /g' file.txt
```

According to `man` page:

```
b label  Branch to the : command bearing the label.
             If label is empty, branch to the end of
             the script.  Labels are recognized unique
             up to eight characters.
```

Since they recognize up to eight characters, if your label is shorter than you'll need to split  your `sed` in multiple expressions.

Answer (score 1):

In the original `sed`, I think a label had to be on a line by itself. From my very ancient `sed & awk` Nutshell book, it states:

A lable is any sequence of up to seven character. A label is put on a line by itself and beginning with a colon:

> `:label`

That means, you need to separate it from the rest of the script with multiple `-e` arguments or see if you have `nawk` or `gawk` on your Solaris box. Alternatively, since it appears you just want to replace all newlines with spaces, there are better tools for the job, such as `tr`, the translate utility, which should *at least* be as ubiquitous as `sed`:

```
a=`tr '\n' ' ' <file.txt`
```